# Getting a property value using a LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

I am trying to write a generic method to allow me to specific a property to retrieve when iterating through a collection:

```
private void WriteStatisticsRow<T>(ICollection<InstitutionStatistics> stats, 
    ICollection<short> years, 
    string statisticsName, 
    string rangeName) where T : struct
{
    Console.WriteLine(statisticsName);

    foreach (short yr in years)
    {
        var stat = stats.SingleOrDefault(s => s.InformationYear == yr);

        if (stat != null)
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(double))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value, format: "0.0");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLin(string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to iterate through the **stats** collection, and write out a specified property's value. I assume that I can use LINQ expressions to do this, but I have no idea how!

Comment: sorry for the question, but what's "value" variable?

Comment: You don't use LINQ to get the value of a property like this; you use *reflection*. There should be lots of information if you search using this term.

Comment: Your code does not match much what you explain, which property you want to get value?

Comment: value is a placeholder for whatever the value of the property is.

Comment: I know how to use reflection to get the property, but I would prefer not to have to use magic strings to get the value of the property.

Answer (score 2):

Use IEnumerable<>.Select():

```cs
var props = collection.Select(x => x.Property);

foreach (var p in props)
{
  Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gets you the values in order of year:

```
foreach (double value in
    from stat in stats
    where years.Contains(stat.InformationYear)
    orderby stat.InformationYear
    select stat.Property)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question, you need to write out InformationYear property's value,so your LINQ expression is as follows :

```
  foreach (double value in
        from stat in stats
        select stat.InformationYear)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
```